# How to get the next element from monix observable?

Tags: scala, stream, observable, monix

I have a stream of data that I casually log, but at a certain state of my program I need the data from the stream, not the latest observed up to that point(I can do that), but the newest one after:

```
val dataStream : Observable[Data] = ...
dataStream
 .doOnNext(logger.trace(_))
 .subscribe()

// ...
// at some state of program later:
// ...
def awaitOneElement(Observable[Data]): Data = ???
val expecting: Data = awaitOneElement(dataStream.filter(...))
```

How do I implement `def awaitOneElement(Observable[Data]): Data = ???`?

I understand it's probably idiomatically incorrect, but that dirty synchronous waiting is exactly what I need. I'm fine with `Observable[Data] => Future[Data]` too, will wrap with `Await` on the next step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
  implicit val scheduler                     = mx
  val pendingPromise: AtomicReference[Option[Promise[A]]] = new AtomicReference(None)
  val lastSubject: ConcurrentSubject[A, A]   = ConcurrentSubject.publish[A]

  o.doOnNext(a => if (pendingPromise.get().nonEmpty) lastSubject.onNext(a))
    .subscribe()

  lastSubject
    .filter(filter)
    .doOnNext(a => pendingPromise.getAndSet(None).map(_.success(a)))
    .subscribe()

  def getNext(duration: Duration): Try[A] = {
    val promise = Promise[A]()
    pendingPromise.set(Some(promise))
    Try(Await.result(promise.future, duration))
  }
}
```

When getNext is called, a `Promise` is created and future is returned. When the desired event occures in Observable, the promise is filled and removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you need exactly one element, you can use something like `Consumer.head` or `Consumer.headOption`:

```scala
val first: Task[Option[Int]] =
  Observable.empty[Int].consumeWith(Consumer.headOption)]
```

And now you can convert task to future. 
If you need all elements you can use foldLeft with accumulator:

```scala
Consumer.foldLeft[T,Vector[T]](Vector.empty[T])((vec, t) => vec :+ t )
```

Or implement custom consumer and fire callback when you need.
Taken from docs: 
https://monix.io/docs/3x/reactive/consumer.html

UPD: 
for last element you can use such consumer:

```scala
Consumer.foldLeft[T,Option[T]](Option.empty[T])((opt, t) => Some(t))
```

Comment: `first` returns first element from the observable, not the last

Comment: @IlyaSmagin ,  you can then use foldLeft without Vector but with Option.